# C# restrict a overriding method to return a specific type

Tags: c#, abstract-class

I have an abstract class which should have a method returning an instance of a class which should inherit from a base class as well implement an interface.

```
public abstract class AbstractClass
{
    abstract [DonotKnowTheType] GetClassInstance() //The Return type should be an instance of a class which implements TestClass and ISample 
}

public class ChildClass : AbstractClass
{
    override [DonotKnowTheType] GetClassInstance()
    {
        //Need to return instance of SampleClass in this example. This could vary, this should be an instance of a class which implements TestClass and ISample
    }
}

public class SampleClass : TestClass,ISample
{
    //Implementation
}
```

Please help to achieve this with a good design. Need to restrict developers who writes the overriding method in ChildClass to return only an instance of a class which implements TestClass and ISample. If not, it has to show a compile time error.

Comment: Is there any way of achieving this?

Comment: Honestly there is no reason for this, to me this is just bad api design.

Comment: @FilipCordas I think its not always bad API design, for example fluent API designs could get great benefit of such feature.

Comment: oow I misunderstood your question, Tim Schemelters answer is the right approach.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public abstract class TheEnforcer<T> where T: TestClass, IMyInterface
    {
        protected abstract T GetClassInstance();
    }

    public class ThePoorClass : TheEnforcer<DerivedTestClass>
    {
        protected override DerivedTestClass GetClassInstance()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public class TestClass
    {

    }

    public class DerivedTestClass : TestClass, IMyInterface
    {

    }

    public interface IMyInterface
    {

    }
```

After your comment:

```
namespace First {
    public abstract class TheEnforcer<T> where T : IMarkerInterface
    {
        protected abstract T GetClassInstance();
    }    

    public interface IMarkerInterface
    {

    } }

namespace Second {
    using First;

    // All this is in separate name space
    public class TestClass: IMarkerInterface
    {

    }

    public class DerivedTestClass : TestClass, IMyInterface
    {

    }

    public interface IMyInterface
    {

    }

    public class ThePoorClass : TheEnforcer<DerivedTestClass>
    {
        protected override DerivedTestClass GetClassInstance()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    } }
```

Comment: TestClass will not be visible in the layer where TheEnforcer class resides

Comment: See the second way. I am using a Marker Interface which is nothing but an empty interface. Hope this solves. Honestly, if you need to do something like this. I guess you have a bad OO design at hand - which should be fixed first.

Answer (score 1):

You could make your abstract class generic with a [contraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters) on `TestClass` and `ISample`:

```
public abstract class AbstractClass<T> where T: TestClass, ISample
{
    public abstract T GetClassInstance(); //The Return type should be an instance of a class which implements AbstractClass and ISample 
}

public class ChildClass : AbstractClass<SampleClass> 
{
    public override SampleClass GetClassInstance()
    {
        //Need to return instance of SampleClass in this example. This could vary, this should be an instance of a class which implements AbstractClass and ISample
        return new SampleClass();
    }
}
```

Comment: By this, it enforces SampleClass to implement ISample, but I need to make sure that it inherits from a baseTestClass too..

Comment: @RandRandom: thought TestClass was a typo, fixed it